# php, the HTTP_REFERER not found

Tags: php, e-commerce

Hi im trying to connect to integrate my form to a payment provider but im getting URL not allowed and it turns out that the HTTP_REFERER is not found..

```
#the following function performs a HTTP Post and returns the whole response
function pullpage( $host, $usepath, $postdata = "" ) {

# open socket to filehandle(epdq encryption cgi)
 $fp = fsockopen( $host, 80, &$errno, &$errstr, 60 );

#check that the socket has been opened successfully
 if( !$fp ) {
    print "$errstr ($errno)<br>\n";
 }
 else {

    #write the data to the encryption cgi
    fputs( $fp, "POST $usepath HTTP/1.0\n");
    $strlength = strlen( $postdata );
    fputs( $fp, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\n" );
    fputs( $fp, "Content-length: ".$strlength."\n\n" );
    fputs( $fp, $postdata."\n\n" );

    #clear the response data
   $output = "";


    #read the response from the remote cgi 
    #while content exists, keep retrieving document in 1K chunks
    while( !feof( $fp ) ) {
        $output .= fgets( $fp, 1024);
    }

    #close the socket connection
    fclose( $fp);
 }

#return the response
 return $output;
}

#define the remote cgi in readiness to call pullpage function 
$server="secure2.epdq.co.uk";
$url="/cgi-bin/CcxBarclaysEpdqEncTool.e";

#the following parameters have been obtained earlier in the merchant's webstore
#clientid, passphrase, oid, currencycode, total
$params="clientid=xxx";
$params.="&password=xxxx";
$params.="&oid=xxxx";
$params.="&chargetype=Auth";
$params.="&currencycode=826";
$params.="&total=120";

#perform the HTTP Post
$response = pullpage( $server,$url,$params );

#split the response into separate lines
$response_lines=explode("\n",$response);

#for each line in the response check for the presence of the string 'epdqdata'
#this line contains the encrypted string
$response_line_count=count($response_lines);
for ($i=0;$i<$response_line_count;$i++){
    if (preg_match('/epdqdata/',$response_lines[$i])){
        $strEPDQ=$response_lines[$i];
    }
}


<FORM action="https://secure2.epdq.co.uk/cgi-bin/CcxBarclaysEpdq.e" method="POST">
<?php print "$strEPDQ"; ?>
<INPUT type="hidden" name="returnurl" value="http://www.xxxxxx.co.uk/test/confirm.php">
<INPUT type="hidden" name="merchantdisplayname" value="xx xxx">
<INPUT type=hidden name=baddr1 value="address line 1">
<INPUT type=hidden name=baddr2 value="address line 2">
<INPUT type=hidden name=baddr3 value="address line 3">
<INPUT type=hidden name=bcity value="City">
<INPUT type=hidden name=bcountyprovince value="County">
<INPUT type=hidden name=bpostalcode value="Postcode">
<INPUT type=hidden name=bcountry value="GB">
<INPUT type=hidden name=btelephonenumber value="01111 012345">
<INPUT type=hidden name=email value="xxxxx">
<INPUT type=hidden name=saddr1 value="Address line 1">
<INPUT type=hidden name=saddr2 value="Address line 2">
<INPUT type=hidden name=saddr3 value="Address line 3">
<INPUT type=hidden name=scity value="City">
<INPUT type=hidden name=scountyprovince value="County">
<INPUT type=hidden name=spostalcode value="Postcode">
<INPUT type=hidden name=scountry value="GB">
<INPUT type=hidden name=stelephonenumber value="01111 012345">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="purchase">
</FORM>
```

can anyone help?

Comment: It's not clear to me how the referer fits into what you're doing.  Who is complaining about it?  The remote site, or you?  There's no guarantee that a referer EVER exists; you cannot rely on it for basically anything.

Comment: yea ive no clue really.. the remote site is complaining about it..

Answer (score 1):

I think some of the other posts deal directly with the issue you are seeing, however, I do want to suggest that you look into using CURL (http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) for what you are trying to do instead of opening a socket connection manually.  Your payment provider might even have some code examples for that in PHP.  Typically this is a much better way of handling communication with gateways and has a lot more flexibility.

This will be especially handy if you integrate with multiple gateways since most have CURL code examples, and you will find other uses for it in the future.

**EDIT:**

Even better than the PHP manual--this site makes it much more clear how to use it including auth routines, passing post vars, etc with examples:

http://devzone.zend.com/article/1081

Comment: I posted that answer while the formatting was jacked--but the suggestion still applies.  =)

Answer (score 0):

```
fputs( $fp, "Referer: ".$somereferer."\n" );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forget the `Host:` header.

But, there are better ways how to POST something via HTTP than opening a socket and implementing your own HTTP client. Try `curl`.